# Symfony functional test transaction issue

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm developing some functional tests for a symfony2 app.

I am facing a problem: when executing a test alone it works fine and leave the database in it's initial state.

But if I execute the whole serie, this test will not be isolated anymore as the database transaction seems to fail to rollback the modifications.

I initialize my tests with fixtures, and then for each tests, if I do some modifications I just use a transaction to rollback them at the end of the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I was setting a memory limit in my tested code somewhere.
Sorry and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use transaction in your functional tests. Functional test often manage to perform complicated flows that require more then one request. Transactions are best if you want to rollback chenges performed only by one request.

You should implement some sort of database clear and load procedure before/after each scenario.

Comment: Ok, but I share the same database connection object accross all requests so I am able to rollback every changes done, but in some precise case its seems to fail

Comment: So please describe this "precise case". I can't help when I don't know details.